# Apostrophe CMS API Create image from attachment

Tags: api, apostrophe-cms

I have uploaded a png as per https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless#attachment-fields and I get back the following;

```
{"_id":"cjlexm6ul000j7ewxnjnse382",
"group":"images",
"createdAt":"2018-08-29T09:22:20.817Z",
"name":"sample1",
"title":"sample1",
"extension":"png",
"type":"attachment",
"docIds":[],
"trashDocIds":[],
"length":226119,
"md5":"3e150a6013f8ea2ffacbbe5a5122a668",
"width":1712,
"height":2537,
"portrait":true,
"ownerId":"cjlcqq0bw000e4qwxpx2cm75u"
}
```

All good but am having issues with turning this into an image. I have tried to add this repose to the POST request as per https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-headless#working-with-apostrophe-images-and-apostrophe-files

```
{
    "title": "sample1",
    "slug": "sample1",
    "attachment": {
    "_id": "cjlexm6ul000j7ewxnjnse382",
    "group": "images",
    "createdAt": "2018-08-29T09:22:20.817Z",
    "name": "sample1",
    "title": "sample1",
    "extension": "png",
    "type": "attachment",
    "docIds": [],
    "trashDocIds": [],
    "length": 226119,
    "md5": "3e150a6013f8ea2ffacbbe5a5122a668",
    "width": 1712,
    "height": 2537,
    "portrait": true,
    "ownerId": "cjlcqq0bw000e4qwxpx2cm75u"
  }
}
```

I am getting back a

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0

on the server...

Any other ideas I can try?

Comment: This parses as valid JSON, but I suspect your POST request is not really using the Content-Type: application/json header, or you have somehow encoded the whole thing into a URL-encoded form field. Would need to see your client code to be sure.

Comment: I put the request into debug to;
`
{ request: 
   { debugId: 1,
     uri: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/apostrophe-images',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: 
      { Authorization: 'Bearer cjlevqzuu000h9pwxy856knw2',
        host: 'localhost:3000',
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'content-length': 443 },
     body: '"{\\"title\\":\\"sample1\\",...TO MUCH JSON TO POST ...."}}"' } }
`

Comment: And here is the sample request ...

`var url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/apostrophe-images',
    accessToken = 'cjlevqzuu000h9pwxy856knw2',
    imageJson = '... JSON FROM ABOVE ....';

var request = require('request');
require('request-debug')(request);

var options = {
    uri: url,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    },
    json: imageJson
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body) // Print the shortened url.
});
`

Comment: Would you please put together a little github project that demonstrates the issue in full so I can tinker and reproduce it?